# jgroups multicast class cast exception

Tags: udp, ehcache, jgroups

I am trying to configure ehcache multicasting to cluster it across two servers. This is what I get.. the error also has the properties I am using to connect. I am not sure if I am missing any properties.

```
net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProvider Failed to create JGroups Channel, replication will not function. 

**JGroups properties:
UDP(mcast_addr=239.255.248.74;mcast_port=9157;):PING:MERGE2:FD_SOCK:VERIFY_SUSPECT:pbcast.NAKACK:UNICAST:pbcast.STABLE:FRAG:pbcast.GMS**

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jgroups.protocols.UDP
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.createLayer(Configurator.java:434)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.createProtocols(Configurator.java:397)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:88)
    at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.setupProtocolStack(Configurator.java:55)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.setup(ProtocolStack.java:449)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.init(JChannel.java:831)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:163)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:143)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProvider.init(JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProvider.java:133)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:471)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:392)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:267)
    at com.loyalty.framework.cache.EhCacheUtil.startupDefaultCache(EhCacheUtil.java:82)
    at com.loyalty.framework.cache.EhCacheUtil.<clinit>(EhCacheUtil.java:37)
    at com.loyalty.ws.vppservice.util.SessionUtil.startupSessionCache(SessionUtil.java:53)
    at com.loyalty.ws.vppservice.util.SessionUtil.<clinit>(SessionUtil.java:33)
    at com.loyalty.ws.vppservice.delegate.AccountDelegate.doSignon(AccountDelegate.java:275)
    at com.loyalty.ws.vppservice.VppServiceProxy.doSignon(VppServiceProxy.java:275)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:92)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.invoke(EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:141)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:172)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:708)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:103)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:311)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:336)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:185)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Answer (score 0):

not trying to dodge the true answer to this... (and I don't quite can think of an answer here) so take this as a FYI. 
Frankly, I'd try to get away from peer-to-peer replication altogether...as it has potential for race conditions and concurrent exceptions + generally is more complex and hard to implement...

If you have the liberty to do it, I'd move towards a distributed caching version of ehcache called BigmemoryMax - http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemorymax (don't be confused by the naming...it's still EhCache...just a distributed process to which ehcache "connects" naturally) which is *free* for up to 4 clients + 4GB of memory storage.

It's very easy to setup and allow you to have numerous clients' cache synchronized seamlessly and supports various enterprise features as well (i.e. transactions, high availability, etc...)